# Jest fails Cannot find module 'react/lib/React' from 'ReactShallowRenderer.js' after React 16 upgrade

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

Just upgraded to react v16.0.0 from v15.6.2 (via a rebase)

**Problem**

Running my jests tests gives the following error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react/lib/React' from 'ReactShallowRenderer.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:16:13)
```

**How I upgraded**

*Step 1: yarn.lock*

During the rebase, onto a branch with React v16 - I let [yarn 1.1.0 take care of merge conflicts](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2155#issuecomment-328068143) on my yarn.lock file

*Step 2: Add adapter*

I added the new adapter *setupTestFramework.js*

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

*Step 3: upgrade packages*

And upgraded the following packages:

```
react "16.0.0",
enzyme "3.1.0",
jest "21.2.1",
babel-jest "21.2.0",
```

Can anyone see anything I missed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When used with React 16, Enzyme requires `v16.x.x` of `react-test-renderer` to be installed.

Comment: I am using `react@16.2.0` and `react-test-renderer@16.2.0` yet I am still seeing this issue.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm currently facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me by following below comand

```
npm uninstall react-dom
```

and then

```
  npm install react-dom --save-dev
```